# Is it okay to connect Supercapacitors as input to Step-up voltage regulator?

Tags: power, capacitor, voltage-regulator, low-power, supercapacitor

I want to use the maximum energy of the supercapacitor for 3.3 powered circuits. Thus, I thought of using step-up voltage regulator like [this](https://www.pololu.com/product/2561/specs)
Can I do this? What are the other suggestions?

Comment: The link is broken.  It's [this](https://www.pololu.com/product/2561/specs)  In general, yes you can do this.  There are not many other simple options when using super caps.  You could put two in series but then you need to worry about balancing them when charging.  Even still it's possible they will discharge to less than 3.3V and you may still want to use them so you would need to consider boost-buck topology.  Your approach would be simpler.

Comment: Great. I am planning use two supercaps of 2.7 volts ( series or parallel) to get 3.3 volts output. Could you please tell me any boost-buck module?

Comment: @AngeloQ And the one I mentioned can take the input of as low as 0.5 volt. That is very efficient as it would still give output 3.3 volts even though supercaps drop down to 0.5 volt. But, would boost-buck take as low as 0.5 volts as an input?

Comment: If you use them in parallel, you don't need boost-buck, just boost, like the one you already identified.  If you use series, you could go with [this regulator](https://www.pololu.com/product/2122).  But again, charging those caps becomes non-trivial.

Comment: No, boost-buck would not generally go to as low a voltage as a straight buck.  You are probably best to stay with the boost-only method.

Comment: @AngeloQ Okay. Great. I am not using more than 3.3 volts in my circuit. Once I connect the load to the circuit super-caps may reach to 0.5 volts, and so this boost module would allow me to use maximum power. Do you know any other high efficient boost module? What is the safe range for charge-discharge of the 2.7 volt super-caps?

Comment: NOTE: You wrote "That is very efficient as it would still give output 3.3 volts even though supercaps drop down to 0.5 volt."  It is able to perform at low voltages, but that doesn't necessarily mean it's more efficient.  Also note that the lower the cap voltage goes, the more current will be drawn from it, and therefore it will discharge faster.  I.e. it may not perform very long once the cap goes below a certain voltage, so the ability to perform in that range may not be of much value.

Comment: @AngeloQ Okay. That is what I wanted to ask. Do you know any other options to get better efficiency? I am charging my supercaps with solar-cells.

Comment: The great thing about caps is there is no issue discharging them fully (to 0V) like with some batteries.  But they have a very different discharge voltage/time profile.  As for charging, definitely keep them under the specified maximum voltage rating.  I'm not sure the efficiency of that module, but if you can get 90% or more you should be doing well.

Comment: @AngeloQ You are right. The [efficiency](https://www.pololu.com/file/0J794/tps6120x-datasheet.pdf) depends on the output current and Vin!

Comment: @AngeloQ You are right. The [efficiency](https://www.pololu.com/file/0J794/tps6120x-datasheet.pdf) depends on the output current and Vin! So do you think there is no other high-efficiency device for low voltage?

Comment: There are a number of options, but I don't know all of them or which would be most efficient.  You would need to start looking into datasheets and comparing efficiency specs.